# How to add the same labels to different categories in R

Tags: r, label, expss

I am using expss::val_lab to add labels to a categorical variable. This is an example of the data I am working with:

```
a<-runif(20,3,9)
a
 [1] 7 4 8 5 6 7 9 9 7 8 4 7 3 8 8 4 7 4 4 5
```

I have problem when I try to add labels with repeated categories:

```
expss::val_lab(a)<-make_labels("
                                3 Bad
                                4 Bad
                                5 Bad
                                6 Regular
                                7 Regular
                                8 Good
                                9 Good
                                ")

expss::val_lab(a)
     Bad     Bad|    Bad||  Regular Regular|     Good    Good| 
       3        4        5        6        7        8        9
```

How can I assign labels properly and get only three categories of labels (bad, regular an good)?

Comment: According to the documentation `Duplicated values are not allowed.`

Comment: If you want to change the vector values then use `setNames(rep(c("Bad", "Regular", "Good"), c(3, 2, 2)), 3:9)[as.character(as.integer(a))]`

Comment: How can I apply it to a larger dataset?

Comment: It works whether it is large or small.  If you check the `a` it can be any vector

Comment: How will you process this variable? Do you want table with three same rows 'bad'? Can you recode 3,4,5 in one category with `a = rec(a, 3:5 ~ 3, TRUE ~ copy)` ?

Comment: I want only three categories: bad, regular and good. I will try to recode it first and then apply this function